# How can I test a PHP script for first Saturday of October?

Tags: php, date

I need a PHP script to display business hours from 1st Saturday in May thru the 1st Saturday in October, then another string for the remainder of the year. Here is what I hobbled together:

```
$this_day = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("Today"));
$first_may = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("First Saturday Of May"));
$first_oct = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("First Saturday Of October"));

$sathours = 'Sat 10am-2pm';
if($this_day >= $first_may && $this_day <= $first_oct) { 
    $sathours = 'Sat by appt only';
} 
echo "$sathours";
```

After creating that, I realized my attempt to test it by redefining the current date

```
$this_day = date('d-m-Y', 02-10-2015);
```

or

```
$this_day = date('02-10-2015');
```

or

```
$this_day = '02-10-2015';
```

does not seem to work (yes, I'm just guessing at how that should work). I'd appreciate some feedback on whether my script is correct and how I should be testing it? Thanks!

Comment: Any issues/questions with answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if($this_day >= $first_may && $this_day <= $first_oct) {
```

is comparing strings, not integers. Because `$this_day`, and others are strings. I'd keep the values as integers. Give this a try..

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$this_day = time();
$first_may = strtotime("First Saturday Of May");
$first_oct = strtotime("First Saturday Of October");
$sathours = 'Sat 10am-2pm';
if($this_day >= $first_may && $this_day <= $first_oct) { 
    $sathours = 'Sat by appt only';
} 
echo "$sathours";
```

[Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given.

Where as [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php),

> Return current Unix timestamp

and if you use that with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

You compare the current time to your two start and end times.